# How to redirect browser to the link present in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a complete newbie to web development.So please forgive me if i am asking a silly question.

I want to create a tool that will add a prefix to link.

Actually I want to create a Text-box in which a link will be pasted and after pasting when I click Go Button the tool should add some prefix to the pasted link and then redirect browser to the new link (i.e. Pasted Link+Prefix Added) .

I somehow managed to write some code that will add prefix to the link pasted in the textbox. But i am unable to make the browser redirect to the new prefixed link.

I tried using " window.location.replace() " for the redirect but its not the solution. Please help me.

```
<script>
function addtext() {
    var newtext = "SOME-PREFIX";
    document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
</script>

<form name="myform">
<textarea name="outputtext" rows="6" column="3"></textarea><br>
<input type="button" value="GO" onClick="addtext();"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: *I tried using " window.location.replace() " for the redirect but its not the solution*  — Yes, it is. We can't tell what you did wrong though, you didn't include your attempt to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?:

```js
function addtext() {
  var newtext = "SOME-PREFIX";
  window.location = document.querySelector("textarea").value + newtext;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <textarea name="outputtext" rows="6" column="3"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="addtext();">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: confused.....I clicked on 'Run Code Snippet' and tried clicking go - nothing happened

Comment: Click run code snippet. Add a link into the textarea, and then you click go and you will be redirected to yourlink + prefix. That what you want?

Comment: I added the code on my site at http://viptechfiles.somee.com/test/ and when i add a link (example.com) in the textarea and clicked go i get redirected to " http://viptechfiles.somee.com/test/example.comSOME-PREFIX  " but i want to get redirected to " example.comSOME-PREFIX "

Comment: Updated my snippet

Comment: almost the same problem instead of  " viptechfiles.somee.com/test/example.comSOME-PREFIX " it redirects to  " viptechfiles.somee.com/test//example.comSOME-PREFIX "

Comment: " viptechfiles.somee.com/test//example.comSOME-PREFIX " changes to  " viptechfiles.somee.com/test/example.comSOME-PREFIX " , i want to omit 'viptechfiles.somee.com/test/' part and want that the browser redirects to 'example.comSOME-PREFIX'

Comment: You have to add http:// prefix to your new URL otherwise it will consider it as a relative URL

Comment: Why you didn't redirect directly to the 'example.comSOME-PREFIX'

Comment: what you mean by redirect directly?

Comment: If I understand correctly the user go to `viptechfiles.somee.com/test/`, fill the form, he is redirected to `viptechfiles.somee.com/test/textareacontentSUFIX` and then to `textareacontentSUFIX`. But you can redirect from `viptechfiles.somee.com/test/` to `textareacontentSUFIX`

Comment: i always wanted to redirect from viptechfiles.somee.com/test/ to textareacontentSUFIX

Comment: So now if you put `http://example.com` into the textarea and click go you will be redirected to `http://example.comSOME-PREFIX`

Comment: You have an extra closing bracket `}` in your javascript code at line 23 on your page, which makes the addtext function not working

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED THANKS TO EVERYONE WHO HELPED!

Comment: thanks fralec bro!! , the culprit was the bracket as pointed out by @simdrouin bro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`window.location.href = document.myform.outputtext.value + newtext;`

As the last line of your addtext function.

[UPDATED]
See a sample here : http://jsbin.com/vodutodaho/edit?js

However it does not redirect inside jsbin